# Recovering deleted file from Spyder file explorer

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

There's a topic on this from November 2016 with an answer stating that it will be implemented in version 3.0.2. I'm running v3.2.3. I've accidentally deleted a folder of scripts in the Spyder file explorer. Is there a way to recover them?

Comment: (*Spyder developer here*) Sorry, we haven't implemented the functionality to recover files or directories deleted through our file explorer yet.

Comment: Luckily in my panic I hadn't realized that I still had the scripts open in Spyder, so I could just save them again. I'd hate to think what would have happened if that wasn't the case.