# Recovering deleted file from Spyder 3.2.6 file explorer

Tags: python, spyder

I got the same problem as of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46497874/4058041). Is there anything changed in Spyder 3.2.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry, nothing has changed about this so far (July/2018). We'll try to address this problem in our next major version (Spyder **4**) to be released in 2019.

Comment: But why do the deleted files not go to trash bin and permanently deleted instead?

Comment: Because Python doesn't have builtin functionality to send a file to the trash but it has to remove it.

Comment: Waiting for v4! One quick workarround could be as other editors not to close the tab of the file deleted (if open) and just ask for name to save. As this would have save the work done if you delete by mistake like me right now :(